# Astropy - Astroquery How to find magnitudes in Simbad?

Tags: python, astropy, astroquery

among other parameters, I am trying to find the magnitudes of some objects using astroquery and Simbad. I think the magnitudes are in 'measurements' votable, but when I invoke `Simbad.add_votable_fields('measurements')` I get an error:

```
Exception: No table found in VOTABLE file
```

The full code example:

```
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
import pandas as pd

inputObject = 'ABELL 2218; M33; M31; M101; M42; M98'
listObject = inputObject.split(';')

Simbad.add_votable_fields('z_value','rv_value','dim_majaxis','dim_minaxis','measurements')

dff = Simbad.query_objects(listObject).to_pandas()


dff.drop(dff.iloc[:, 3:11], inplace=True, axis=1)   #delete some columns
dff.drop(dff.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)     #also drop last column
Simbad.remove_votable_fields('z_value','rv_value','dim_majaxis','dim_minaxis','measurements')
#show data
dff.style.format(precision=5,na_rep='No data')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mags are in the VOtable fields:

```
flux(B), flux(V), flux(R), flux(I)
```